# Tkinter textfield size doesn't reach frame size

Tags: text, tkinter

The textfield does't expand to the size of textfield_frame = frame. Why?
Later I want to place more widgets into more frames, that's why here i started with one frame inside the root frame.
thanks in advance.

```
import Tkinter

root = Tkinter.Tk()

ScreenSizeX = root.winfo_screenwidth()
ScreenSizeY = root.winfo_screenheight()
FrameSizeX = int(ScreenSizeX * 0.7)
FrameSizeY = int(ScreenSizeY * 0.7)
FramePosX = (ScreenSizeX - FrameSizeX)/2
FramePosY = (ScreenSizeY - FrameSizeY)/2

root.geometry("%dx%d%+d%+d"%(FrameSizeX,FrameSizeY,FramePosX,FramePosY))
frame = Tkinter.Frame(root)
frame.pack()

textfield_frame_height = FrameSizeY
textfield_frame = Tkinter.Frame(frame,width=FrameSizeX,height=ScreenSizeY,bg="yellow")

textfield_frame.pack()    

text = Tkinter.Text(textfield_frame)
text.pack(fill="both", expand=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Textfield` fits to `textfield_frame` exactly. But `textfield_frame` and `frame` do not fit to `root`:

```
frame.pack(fill="both", expand=1)
textfield_frame.pack(fill="both", expand=1)
```